# Ability to run a `Gulp` task from code instead of command line

Tags: javascript, gulp

I tried this following:

```js
const gulpFile = require('./gulpfile') 
gulpFile.default();
```

and "it works", it executed the `default` task defined from the `gulpfile.js`

I just need to know if this way is recommanded ?
And if it's documented somewhere

Answer (score 0):

If youre using ES6 or above you could simply try importing the gulpfile

```
import gulpFile from './gulpfile';
gulpFile.default();
```

If you're using ES5 or below, then I assume your way is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking if there is any documentation to run a `gulp` task without the command line